# haproxy does not load balance when one server in farm is down

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, ubuntu-14.04

I have three back end servers load balanced using HAProxy.

When all 3 of those are up i see each servers Id (1,2,3) consecutively in the HTTPS response. IE 1,2,3,1,2,3. As expected.

However, if i take one back end server down i then only see one server id repeatedly.

I.e if I take server 1 down I then only see server id 2 (2,2,2,2...) when I should see server id's 2,3 (2,3,2,3,2,3.....)

I have tried both leastconn and round robin balancing and both exhibit the same behaviour

Why does HAProxy behave this way? How do I alter my HAProxy config to  load balance across the remaining alive back end servers?

HA proxy version is 1.6.9. Server for HA proxy is ubuntu 14.04.

The HTTP being served is an API that returns some JSON over HTTPS. Its a restful API so there is no session persistence required or wanted.

The configuration for haproxy is below.

```
 global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    maxconn 3072
    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private
    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:RC4-SHA:!kEDH$
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option dontlog-normal
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    maxconn 3072
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  10000
    timeout server  10000

frontend apis-frontend
    bind x.x.x.x:443 ssl verify none crt /etc/haproxy/xxx
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    default_backend apis

backend apis
    balance leastconn
    mode http
    option httpchk GET /
    server 1 x.x.x.x:443 ssl verify none check
    server 2 x.x.x.x:443 ssl verify none check
    server 3 x.x.x.x:443 ssl verify none check

listen stats
    bind *:8181
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth xx
```

Edit: added stats.

```
pxname,svname,qcur,qmax,scur,smax,slim,stot,bin,bout,dreq,dresp,ereq,econ,eresp,wretr,wredis,status,weight,act,bck,chkfail,chkdown,lastchg,downtime,qlimit,pid,iid,sid,throttle,lbtot,tracked,type,rate,rate_lim,rate_max,check_status,check_code,check_duration,hrsp_1xx,hrsp_2xx,hrsp_3xx,hrsp_4xx,hrsp_5xx,hrsp_other,hanafail,req_rate,req_rate_max,req_tot,cli_abrt,srv_abrt,comp_in,comp_out,comp_byp,comp_rsp,lastsess,last_chk,last_agt,qtime,ctime,rtime,ttime,
apis-frontend,FRONTEND,,,0,2,3072,24,9118,10021,0,0,19,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,2,0,,,,0,0,0,4,,,,0,24,0,19,0,0,,0,6,43,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,
apis,mt-wol-vlx-vps-01,0,0,0,1,,12,4863,3240,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,1,0,12097,0,,1,3,1,,12,,2,0,,2,L7OK,200,36,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,,,,,39,OK,,0,1,1,29,
apis,mt-lon-vlx-vps-01,0,0,0,1,,12,4255,3228,,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,1,1,0,0,0,12097,0,,1,3,2,,12,,2,0,,2,L7OK,200,23,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,,,,,39,OK,,0,1,1,5,
apis,mt-cov-uks-vps-01,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,DOWN,1,1,0,1,1,12094,12094,,1,3,3,,0,,2,0,,0,L4TOUT,,2001,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,0,0,,,,,-1,,,0,0,0,0,
apis,BACKEND,0,0,0,1,308,24,9118,6468,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,2,2,0,,0,12097,0,,1,3,0,,24,,1,0,,3,,,,0,24,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,,,0,1,1,33,
stats,FRONTEND,,,1,4,3072,10,3811,169181,0,0,5,,,,,OPEN,,,,,,,,,1,4,0,,,,0,1,0,4,,,,0,9,0,5,0,0,,1,3,15,,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,
stats,BACKEND,0,0,0,0,308,0,3811,169181,0,0,,0,0,0,0,UP,0,0,0,,0,12097,0,,1,4,0,,0,,1,0,,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,0,18,
```

edit: load balancing behaviour in different browsers

After a request to test from a different ip. I noticed the second ip load balanced as expected. I then tried from the first IP but using different browsers edge and firefox. Both edge and firefox load balance as expected.

However the original browser chrome still stick to one back end server. Even after closing all chrome windows and restarting chrome

Comment: can you show how the apis is configured into the backend

Comment: Do you mean the back-end haproxy config? That's there just scroll down.

Comment: yes - sorry . if you take one server down and you look at the stats page (append ;csv) what do you see ? normally for http I use rr as balance algo.

Comment: no problem! thank you for taking an interest. I have added the stats to the question.

Comment: I'm no haproxy expert. But when I look at the stats web page it looks like it thinks its load balancing to both the remaining servers. However it definitely isn't as I only see one server id.

Comment: I see - try to send requests from two different ip address (clients) seems like you get 'stick' to the same server.

Comment: ok when i use a second computer with a different IPs . computer 2 (ipad via a vpn) load balances as expected ie 2,3,2,3. However the original computer (windows desktop) still sticks ie 2,2,2. Our api is called from companies using a very small number of source IPs per company for a large amount of requests. So we are trying to load balance many requests from a handful of IPs

Comment: I see - so you worry that you end up with a single server, in fact is not like that if you shutdown the server that you 'stick' you will be redirected to the next one. Haproxy has what is called affinity and this is what it happens in your case. You can configure the rr algo.

Comment: see edit it seems this may? be a chrome issue but i do not know how.

Comment: Thats the problem i cannot have a large amount of requests going to a single server, even from one ip. we could get 100 requests per second from one source ip and they must be distributed across the remaining live servers

Comment: try to change from lc to  balance roundrobin

Comment: same behaviour with round robin :(

Comment: that is odd - do you have access to the http headers ? see if is a cookie inserted by haproxy.

Comment: it is odd. No headers inserted by haproxy. the only failure to load balance when one server is down just seems to be in chrome. I'm confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46166/discussion-between-simon-hodkinson-and-silviud).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much further testing the behaviour indicated only appears when using Google's Chrome browser. Why chrome shows this behaviour is undetermined.

The observed behaviour was not a HAProxy issue.

This tested multiple times with other browsers and other clients. Final proof being live service for several hours.

The HAProxy config above has now been running for several hours and is fairly distributing traffic amongst the three servers. This is evidenced from our DB records which records server id. Over a period of several hours each server was assigned the same number of requests within +- 50 from circa 4,500 requests.

More importantly, given the original question, it also continues to distribute fairly in the event of failure of one of the servers, amongst the other two. Again evidenced by our DB records which record server id. When measured over 15 minutes a clear pattern of equally balanced server ids can be seen in our DB records.

A poignant reminder to design testing to pin point where an issue lies, before assuming the issue lies with the part(s) of the solution you don't know very well, yet.

Thank you for the many replies it took for that realisation to dawn.